# Radiobutton with text on top

Tags: android, radio-button

How do you make a radiobutton where you change the drawable with android:button and have text on top? with regular radio buttons the text is layered behind the drawable.

Right now I'm starting to get out in a frustrated implementation of my own radiobutton.

I want something like this:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <RadioButton
        android:text="something that is on top"
        android:id="@+id/toggle_tab_left"
        android:button="@drawable/main_selector"
        style="@style/TabStyle"/>
    <RadioButton 
        android:button="@drawable/info_selector"
        android:text="something that is on top"
        android:id="@+id/toggle_tab_right"
        style="@style/TabStyle"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: what do you exactly want tell me?

Comment: try using RadioButton  gravity.

Comment: How should the gravity help? I want it on top/above visually on top like in Z axis not x/y axis. The problem is the image sits on top of the text so you can't read it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `background` attribute for the graphic instead, and set the `button` to @null or a transparent color.