# Radiobutton with text above button

Tags: android, radio-button

I am new to android and I need to add radio buttons on my activity, but i need to place the text on the to of the bullet button.

Any help please. I found the following, though I dont understand what the @drawable/main_selector and @style/TabStyle.

[Radiobutton with text on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106726/radiobutton-with-text-on-top)

Can anyone give me a 101 guide.

**UPDATE**

I used the following according to some suggestion but didnt work:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RadioButton
    android:text="something that is on top"
    android:id="@+id/toggle_tab_left"
    android:button="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"        
    style="@null"/>

<RadioButton 
    android:button="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:text="something that is on top"
    android:id="@+id/toggle_tab_right"
    style="@null"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I got my solution from Warpzit, but befor i mark the question as answered, can someone help me on the alignment issue below. 
I will have 5 radio buttons in a row where some of them will have longer text split in 2 lines. when the text fit on the screen, because of landscape, or on tablets then all text should be in one line:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

... depending on the screen size the text can split into different number of lines. It wont be always standard

[image]

Comment: This question was down-voted and i don't understand why. It is very well asked with clear objective. Proof is that it was even answered correctly very quickly !!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `@style/TabStyle` is simply a style that is applied, you can ignore that. The `@drawable/main_selector` is a graphic that is toggled depending on the situation. You can read more about selectors [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Example to get text **on top**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RadioButton
    android:text="Text on top"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<RadioButton 
    android:text="Text on top"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Will give following result:

[image: Behind, text on top example]

If you want the Text to appear **above** the button you can use following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<RadioButton
    android:text="Text on top"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<RadioButton
    android:text="Text on top"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

This will give following result:

[image: Above example]

Comment: can i use the default button, the bullet, instead of @drawable/main_selector

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos yes but what is pointed out is that the button drawable should be "@null" and you should override the background instead.

Comment: please check my update. The text is still aligned on the right. Do you have a vanilla example for this?

Comment: thanks it works! I have a vertical alignment issue now as per update 2. Can you please advise on that too. You got the answer correct, so I will mark it as correct anyway.

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos I don't get you issue. Do you want the text to hide when too long or what are you fishing after?

Comment: I need to bottom align the bullets

Comment: @YiannisStavrianos they are bottom aligned... You should set the height of the RadioButtons to something fixed (80dp etc.) and then you'll get the kind of layout you want.

Comment: I tried that and its kind of what I need. According to screen size the lines of the text can be 1, 2 or more. I wont be able to set the height every time the screen size changes. See Update 3

Comment: Unfortunately this produces weird results. I have 4 radio buttons in row. The texts are either wrapped or cut. Basically they are unable to have a greater width than the width of the button itself. Therefore my solution would be to use a separate linear layout with texts and separate one with buttons.

Comment: @Yar There's no need to make the hierachy more complex. See my answer, a RadioGroup is enough.

Comment: By all angles perfect answer

Answer (score 26):

To complement [Warpzit great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102926/350040), you should use `android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on the buttons, to align them.

Also there's no need to copy the radio button drawables from AOSP, use `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle`.

[image: Screenshot]

### XML Layout

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="RadioButton dsfsdfsdfsdfsdf" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="RadioButton fdsfsd fdsfsdf fsfsdfs" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: How can I do it if I am adding radio buttons problematically in the radiogroup

Comment: @IshaanPuniani Prepare and set a RadioGroup.LayoutParams on each button before adding the button to the RadioGroup

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to make this effect easy to apply is to use a style. To do that, place this code on your `styles.xml`, under the `resources` tag.

```
<style name="RadioWithTextOnTop">
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:drawableBottom">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|bottom</item>
</style>
```

And then, apply it to your RadioButton like this:

```
<RadioButton
    style="@style/RadioWithTextOnTop"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I ended up using is:

```
<RadioButton
    ...
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:drawableTop="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:button="@null"
    />
```

It also uses the newer style of the animated icon `listChoiceIndicatorSingle` which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"[enter image description here][1]
                    android:background="@drawable/app_border_0"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:text="@string/no"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    style="@style/AppRadioAppStyle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
```

should be add android:button="@null" in your radiobutton