# Radio button text to top of the button programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

Is there any way to align the text of radio button to the top like below programmatically.

[image]

i used the below code for creating radio group

```
  final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
            RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity()); //create the RadioGroup
            rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
            rg.setLayoutParams(radioparams);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
                rb[i].setText("Radiobtn " + i);
                rb[i].setId(i + 100);
                rg.addView(rb[i]);

            }
            layout.addView(rg);
```

but i get the text to the right side of each button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102159/radiobutton-with-text-above-button

Comment: i want to implement it programitically

Comment: You can achieve this by creating a custom radio button and add it dynamically to the views.
Refer: https://crosp.net/blog/android/creating-custom-radio-groups-radio-buttons-android/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity()); //create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    rg.setLayoutParams(radioparams);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        rb[i].setText("Radiobtn " + i);
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rb[i].setButtonDrawable(null);

        TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, new int[] {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorSingle});
        int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(attributeResourceId);

        rb[i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, drawable);
        rb[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);

    }
    layout.addView(rg);
```

Comment: how can i change the radio button color. ?

Comment: `DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.BLUE);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way you can do a trick

make your layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


</LinearLayout>
```

than add programatically `RadioButton` like this

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);

            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            final TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            int id = 0;
            textView.setId(id);
            textView.setTextSize(14);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
            textView.setMaxEms(2);
            textView.setText("NIlu");
            layout2.addView(textView);

            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
            layout2.addView(radioButton);
            layout.setLayoutParams(lp);

            lnrView.addView(layout2);


        }
    });
```

Comment: i only want to set the radio button text to top, so is there a need to use textview?